# Four Way Intersection Simulation

Tags: java, object

I'm trying to write a program that displays the light sequences at a four way intersection.

The direcitons are:

At any given time the traffic can only move in one direction.  Traffic lights have three colors RED, YELLOW and GREEN.  Based on an event.  The lights change color in a synchronized way to allow for safe driving.  Define a class called “TrafficLight” which has two methods.  One called “change” and another which is called “getColor”.  In a separate class “Assignment5”, with the main entry point, I want you to create 4 TrafficLight instances two for North/South traffic and two for East/West traffic.  Using the two methods the objects provide I want you to show that you have correctly simulated the four way traffic light.

[image: I also need to implement these into the program.]

So far i have:

```
 public class TrafficLight {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public TrafficLight(int c){
    this.c = c;

}//end constructor 

public int getC(){
    return c;
}

java.lang.String getColor;
    String n = "GYR";
    String s = "GYR";
    String e = "GYR";
    String w = "GYR";


public void change(){
    int c = 1;

     while (c <= 4){
         if (c == 1){
            n.charAt(2);
            s.charAt(2);
            e.charAt(0);
            w.charAt(0);
            c++;
         }
         else if (c == 2){
            n.charAt(2);
            s.charAt(2);
            e.charAt(1);
            w.charAt(1);
            c++;
         }
         else if (c == 3){
            n.charAt(0);
            s.charAt(0);
            e.charAt(2);
            w.charAt(2);
            c++;
         }
         else if (c == 4){
            n.charAt(1);
            s.charAt(1);
            e.charAt(2);
            w.charAt(2);
            c++;
         }

         while (c >= 5)
             if (c-4 == 1){
                n.charAt(2);
                s.charAt(2);
                e.charAt(0);
                w.charAt(0);
                c++;
             }
             else if (c-4 == 2){
                n.charAt(2);
                s.charAt(2);
                e.charAt(1);
                w.charAt(1);
                c++;
             }
             else if (c-4 == 3){
                n.charAt(0);
                s.charAt(0);
                e.charAt(2);
                w.charAt(2);
                c++;
             }
             else if (c-4 == 4){
                n.charAt(1);
                s.charAt(1);
                e.charAt(2);
                w.charAt(2);
                c++;
             }

        System.out.println(n);
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println(w);

     }//end inner while loop

}//end 'change'

 private int c;


 }//end class
```

The sample output should look something like:

```
Traffic light event 1: 
North light: Red
South light: Red
East light: Green
West light: Green

Traffic light event 2: 
North light: Red
South light: Red
East light: Yellow
West light: Yellow

Traffic light event 3: 
North light: Green
South light: Green
East light: Red
West light: Red

Traffic light event 4: 
North light: Yellow
South light: Yellow
East light: Red
West light: Red

Traffic light event 5: 
North light: Red
South light: Red
East light: Green
West light: Green

Traffic light event 6: 
North light: Red
South light: Red
East light: Yellow
West light: Yellow

Traffic light event 7: 
North light: Green
South light: Green
East light: Red
West light: Red

Traffic light event 8: 
North light: Yellow
South light: Yellow
East light: Red
West light: Red

Traffic light event 9: 
North light: Red
South light: Red
East light: Green
West light: Green

Traffic light event 10: 
North light: Red
South light: Red
East light: Yellow
West light: Yellow

Traffic light event 11: 
North light: Green
South light: Green
East light: Red
West light: Red

Traffic light event 12: 
North light: Yellow
South light: Yellow
East light: Red
West light: Red
```

How would i go about implementing this? Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you know what `charAt` actually does?

Comment: My teacher told us it was to call on the array from `java.lang.String`. I'm guessing it's not?

Comment: Well, it finds out what one character in a String is; but it doesn't change the String in any way.  So calling it, then not using the return value from it will do absolutely nothing.  That applies to 32 lines of your program.

Comment: I'm not trying to change the values, just finding what they are then printing them.

Comment: Understood.  But you're not actually printing the values that are returned from `charAt`.  You're printing each entire string.  So this is always just going to print `GYR` over and over.

Comment: Why not just write things like `n = "Green";` (or whatever), where you've currently got things like `n.charAt(0);`?  I think this is what you intended to have.

Comment: If I did that, then I'd have to get rid of `java.lang.String getColor`?

Comment: What are you actually doing with that `getColor` variable?  I can't see that you've used it at all.

Comment: Just using it as a placeholder for the string values GYR.

Comment: OK, I think it's time for you to implement my suggestion, then have a good think about whether you need `getColor` or not.

Comment: I get what you're saying, it's useless code. But I need a `getColor` method. I know I'm not using it correctly.

Comment: You've declared a field though, not written a method.

Comment: How would I go about changing it into a method?

Comment: I don't mean to sound condescending, but if you're unsure of the difference between a field and a method, it might be a good idea to spend some time looking back over your notes for this course.